# After i added some dependencies in my updated android studio version 4.0.1,

Tags: android-studio, dependencies

I faces with 3 errors.
*upgrade plugin to version 4.0.1 & sync project
*project may be using a version of gradle that does not contain the method
*Apply gradle plugin

My android gradle plugin version is already 4.0.1 still error is showing upgrade plugin
to version 4.0.1 .

Comment: Please post the full error message via the code markup

Answer (score 1):

Goto File -> Project Structure

Within the project set Your Gradle version to the latest version.

This might help.

[image]